# My nodejs express and passport application redirects me to the user object when posting to the login route

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport.js

I've setup a fairly simple login application using express mongodb and passportjs

Everything seems to work except when I post to the login route I get the user object return to me instead of the home route, I'm quite confused, I've had a look at the docs for passport but not sure what's causing this.

Server.js code

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  //console.log('Serialise User Called ' + user.id);
  done(null, user.id)
});
passport.deserializeUser( async function (id, done) {
  try {
    //console.log('Deserilise user called ' + id);
    id = await User.findById(id).exec();
    console.log(id);
    done(id)
  } catch (error) {
    done(error)
  }
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(async function (username, password, done) {
    try {
      const user = await User.findOne({ username: username }).exec();
    if(!user) return done(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect username'})
      bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function (err, res) {
          if (err) return done(err);
            if(res === false) return done(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect Password'})
            console.log('finished localstrategy');
            return done(null, user);
        })
    } catch (error) {
     console.log('Local strat error' + error);
     done(null, error) 
    }

}));

// app.get("/", isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
//   res.redirect("home");
// });

app.use("/", loginRouter)

app.use("/home", isLoggedIn, homeRouter)

app.use('/register', registerRouter)

app.use('/list', isLoggedIn, listRouter)

app.use('/login', loginRouter)

app.use('/logout', logoutRouter)

app.use('/request', isLoggedIn, requestRouter)

function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()){
    console.log('Authenticated');
    return next();
  }
 console.log('Not authenticated'); 
 res.redirect("/login");
}
```

login.js router

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const User = require("../models/User.js");
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
var passport = require("passport")

router.get("/", function (req, res) {
    console.log('Login called');
    res.render("login");
  });

router.post("/",function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('Login post called');
    next();
}, passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/home',
    failureRedirect: '/login?error=true'
}));

module.exports = router
```

Sorry if this question is quite obvious, also the console logs the following;

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("64dfe4319cc137b5818cfeda"),
  username: 'john3',
  password: '$2b$10$lpEwg.KHmAoBFx2bu5WD8.4U/blUB1UZT1r5I4O9lt2kustP6HyNK',
  __v: 0
}
{
  _id: new ObjectId("64dfe4319cc137b5818cfeda"),
  username: 'john3',
  password: '$2b$10$lpEwg.KHmAoBFx2bu5WD8.4U/blUB1UZT1r5I4O9lt2kustP6HyNK',
  __v: 0
}
```

So it's getting the user and verifying and displaying the above correct user on the screen but the title of the html that's returned to the user says error.

I've tried going through and logging each step to make sure it's running through the code as expected and it seems to be hitting all the routes except for the home one and gives the user object instead

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question,

I returned from the deserializeUser function the user as the error rather than null,

1 simple line

from

```
passport.deserializeUser( async function (id, done) {
  try {
    //console.log('Deserilise user called ' + id);
    id = await User.findById(id).exec();
    console.log(id);
    done(id)
  } catch (error) {
    done(error)
  }
});
```

to

```
passport.deserializeUser( async function (id, done) {
  try {
    //console.log('Deserilise user called ' + id);
    id = await User.findById(id).exec();
    console.log(id);
    **done(null, id)**
  } catch (error) {
    done(error)
  }
});
```